# In Julia, Transpose operator

Tags: julia, transpose

I am trying to use a transpose operator over a vector in order to perform am element-wise addition.
For example, I want to add a column vector `a = [a1;a2;a3]` to a row vector `b = [b1,b2]` I should get matrix
`M = a+b = [a1+b1, a1+b2; a2+b1, a2+b2; a3+b1, a3+b2]`.
In MATLAB it is equivalent (if both vectors are row vectors) `M = a.'+b`

I am trying to get the same in Julia but here is the problem, there is no `.'` operator in Julia starting from 1.0 version. There is the transpose operator which does not work in broadcasting mode. The adjoint operator is not Valid for me because I work with complex numbers.

```
a = Vector{ComplexF64}([1+3im,2])
b = Vector{ComplexF64}([0,0,0])
Z = zeros(ComplexF64,3,2)
G = zeros(ComplexF64,3,2)


@. Z = b + a'           # Works but takes the complex conjugate
@. Z = b + transpose(a) # DOES NOT WORK!!!! The error is " DimensionMismatch("array could not be broadcast to match destination") "
Z = b .+ transpose(a)   # Works but not efficient
@. Z = b + conj(a')
```

The third case `Z = b .+ transpose(a)` is not efficient because it makes 2 loops first one for addition `b .+ transpose(a)`, than it runs the second loop one for the assignment  of `b .+ transpose(a)` to `Z`. While the other 3 cases do it within one loop.
So which is the fastest way? 
And why transpose doesn't within Broadcasting?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

For Hermitian You can just type:

```
a' .+ b
```

Example

```
julia> a = ComplexF64.([1+3im,2])
2-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
 1.0 + 3.0im
 2.0 + 0.0im

julia> b = ComplexF64.([10,20,30])
3-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
 10.0 + 0.0im
 20.0 + 0.0im
 30.0 + 0.0im

julia> a' .+ b
3×2 Array{Complex{Float64},2}:
 11.0-3.0im  12.0+0.0im
 21.0-3.0im  22.0+0.0im
 31.0-3.0im  32.0+0.0im
```

If you want to have just transposition you could define your own unary operator (perhaps from the list of unused unary operators):

```
¬(a) = permutedims(a)
```

Now you could do

```
julia> ¬a
1×2 Matrix{ComplexF64}:
 1.0+3.0im  2.0+0.0im
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent the complex conjugate from being taken...

Comment: This is not the transpose, it is the Hermitian

Comment: yes indeed this is Hermitian - I edited the answer